# Converting WMS GetMap request to GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, wms, shell

I'm accessing a WMS server that doesn't provide GeoTIFF as one of the format capabilities, but does provide PNG and KMZ.

http://tds.marine.rutgers.edu:8081/ncWMS/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0

I'm thinking that it should be possible to write a little shell script that would either:

1. Request KMZ and convert that to GeoTIFF, using the implied SRS and bounding box info
2. Request PNG and use the WMS query bounding box and SRS to create the GeoTIFF, perhaps using gdal or similar

Has anyone done something like this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulx=-76.80
lrx=-67.85
lry=34.58
uly=41.71
crs=EPSG:4326
url="http://tds.marine.rutgers.edu:8081/ncWMS/wms?LAYERS=espresso_4dvar%2Ftemp&ELEVATION=-0.986111111111111&TIME=2013-08-20T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES=boxfill%2Frainbow&CRS=$crs&COLORSCALERANGE=2.156%2C28.6&NUMCOLORBANDS=254&LOGSCALE=false&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=XML&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=$ulx,$lry,$lrx,$uly&WIDTH=1024&HEIGHT=1024"
curl -o foo.png $url 
gdal_translate -a_srs ${crs} -a_ullr $ulx $uly $lrx $lry foo.png foo.tif
```

Fixed the typo

Comment: Okay, so just feed the BBOX and CRS to both the WMS request and to the gdal_translate command.  That make sense.  And works.  Thanks!

Comment: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-April/035951.html seems to suggest you can do it directly in gdal_translate - I've not tried though

Comment: This is why I love GSE!