# Exporting to GeoTIFF creates unreasonable large files

Tags: qgis, gdal, wms, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to produce a high quality image of a geological structural map provided for at this exact WMS link (The link includes the dimensions I wanted and the max possible resolution they provide)

```
http://maps.greenmin.gl/geusmap/ows/32624.jsp?nocache=nocache&whoami=[email]&LAYERS=grl_geus_500k_geology_map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A32624&BBOX=499980.0,7190220.0,609780.0,7400040.0&WIDTH=1500&HEIGHT=3000
```

I tried asking the question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299495/gdal-translate-with-wms-troubles), but had no luck with anyone providing me with an answer. I've also tried working it out like [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69188/converting-wms-getmap-request-to-geotiff), without luck. So instead I've tried a different approach of using the Layer -> Save as function in QGIS. 
Which is partially successful. I am able to output a geo referenced TIFF of the region with the desired dimensions. But for some reason that is beyond me, the file size is 92 gb and every program I try to open it in, chokes hard. This map is an exact matching overlay of a Sentinel-2 satellite image, in high quality, geo referenced and with a file size of about 1 gb. It ought to be possible for me to do something like that.

It would also be fine if I could get it without a georeference, I can add that manually. I just cannot fathom why it is so hard to have QGIS output a large dimensional image without producing ridiculous file sizes.

Has anyone dealt with anything like this and found a suitable solution or work around?

[image]

Comment: Hello Peter, also the create options of the Save raster layer as ... makes compressing available on the image.

Comment: Hi @Jakob, 
I tried doing that. But every time I tick it and run it, it pops an error saying "Cannot validate creation options"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking (in all these questions) for an image that is 200k*100k pixels in size - that is 20,000,000,000 or 20 billion pixels each with 3 bands so 60 billion bytes (or worse floats or doubles) so it is going to be a big file unless you add some compression.

If you are basing it on the WMS request then asking for more than 1500 by 3000 pixels is a waste anyway as that is the resolution you get.

Comment: Doh... I've been stuck on this for days now...
And some times all you need is a second pair of eyes. The image is being output with an 0 to much at the end of the x,y dimensions. I didn't notice that until you mentioned it. And as you said I might as well reduce it even further.
Thank you Ian.